# Stop setting values based on Timezone in Kendo bar chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using Kendo Bar Chart to implement graph in ASP.NET MVC. But it displays the graph values based on the Timezone in local machine. So, the graph value is not same for all people.

I am using below code in Kendo to show Bar Chart

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
.Name("chartCampaignPerformance")
.HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:100%" })
.Title("")
.Events(ev => ev.DataBound("chartCampPerfColorChange"))
    .ChartArea(chartArea => chartArea.Background("Transparent"))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Read(read => read.Action("", ""))
    .Group(group => group.Add(model => model.GroupValue))
    .Sort(sort => sort.Add(model => model.DateValue).Ascending())
    )
 .Series(series =>
 {
     series.Column(model => model.ItemCount, categoryExpression: model => model.DateValue, colorExpression: (model => model.ItemColor))
         .Aggregate(ChartSeriesAggregate.Sum).Gap(.50).Name("#= group.value #");

 })
.CategoryAxis(axis => axis
    .Date()
    .BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Months)
    .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
)
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Visible(true)
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)

    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()

        .Labels(labels => labels
            .Format("{0}")
            .Skip(2)
            .Step(2)
        )
    )
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
            .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
        )
)
```

}

**IST Timezone chart**

[image]

**CST Timezone chart**

[image]